# Sum of product of binomial coefficients & powers: closed-form?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, binomial-coefficients

The following sum has emerged in my research:

$
\sum_{j=k}^{n}\frac{1}{2^j}{j\choose k}{n+k+2\choose n-j};
$

I am looking for a closed form for this sum (without hypergeometric series). I have searched through Graham, Knuth and Patashnik's *Concrete Mathematics* and could not locate any identities which could be used to simplify this sum, or express it in closed-form (without hypergeometric series).

Does anyone know a way to express this sum in closed-form?

Comment: If you set $k = 0$ and multiply the whole thing with $2^n$, you get $F\left(n\right) := \sum\limits_{j=0}^n 2^{n-j} \dbinom{n+2}{n-j} = 3^{n+2} - 2^{n+2} - \left(n+2\right)2^{n+1}$. Wondering what sort of formula would be possible for general $k$; this doesn't seem to nicely generalize.

Comment: With $k=1$ you get $2^{-n} 3^{n+2} (n-6)+n (n+13)+54$ and $k=2$ you get $\frac{1}{6} \left(2^{-n} 3^{n+3} ((n-17) n+96)-2 (n (n (n+27)+296)+1296)\right)$.